# Mimic CLI curl with PHP curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to replicate a command line curl with php curl. Something is not working, can you see why?

CLI version that I want to mimic

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: textSearchAction" --data @searchRequest.xml http://somedomain/services/Service | tidy -xml -i
```

This is what I've tried

```
$rCurlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somedomain/services/Service');
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('searchRequest.xml'));
$aHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'SOAPAction: textSearchAction',
);

curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aHeaders);
$sResponse = curl_exec($rCurlSession);
```

The first command returns an xml which I expect, the last one gives me an error message xml. It only says "unknown error" so I find it hard to know where my input is wrong.

Comment: What if, instead of using `file_get_contents`, you specify the filename there instead, as with the standard cURL command (e.g. use this instead: `curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '@searchRequest.xml');`).

Comment: Nah that dosn't seemt to work, I't wont read the file but just passing '@searchRequest.xml' as payload.

Answer (score 1):

Some essential `curl` parameters are missing from your script. Use the following (mind the use of `$xmlData`):

```
$xmlData = file_get_contents('searchRequest.xml');
$rCurlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somedomain/services/Service');
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlData);
$aHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'SOAPAction: textSearchAction',
    'Content-length: '.strlen($xmlData),
);

curl_setopt($rCurlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aHeaders);
$sResponse = curl_exec($rCurlSession);
```